# Can i export the details in Launch to any other system? Is there any exposed API to do this?

Tags: reportportal

I wanted to export the BDD execution details to my application and display the execution details in the application. Is there any exposed API that would help me to get the entire data in the launches tab for a particular project?

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed API documentation based on Swagger: 
https://{YOUR_RP_INSTANCE}/ui/#api

Regarding the results, there are basically two ways to achieve that:

- There is export functionality, you can generate launch report in some XLS format
  (see `GET /{projectName}/launch/{launchId}/report`)
- Write some scripts in order to get get launch over API, then GET its descendants by launch ID and so on.
  (see `GET /{projectName}/launch`, GET `/{projectName}/item`)